# Teams calendar and Outlook integration

Tags: sharepoint-online, outlook, microsoft-teams

I have teams channel with calendar created but In the early days it was possible to create and integrate calendar to outlook. Now when teams channel is created cannot find that in Browse groups outlook.

How to integrate teams channel and outlook